# Best Practice for ini file locations specifically for custom scripts that you want to run as a package

Tags: python

I am new to python and been assigned a small project at work. I am writing a simple email script to be used for many other python jobs for various paths etc (all on same server). The email functionality is working that is not the issue. the issue lies in detecting the .ini and the best approach to achieving the goal.

For the sake of this post. these are the following Directory Locations and names

```
C:/Python_Custom_Packages/Classes/Email.py #Email Script
C:/Python_Custom_Packages/Conf/Email_config.ini  #Email Config 

C:/Example_Project/Test_Job_Email.py #Test Job that will call the script
```

to get email.py to read Email_config.ini im using the following:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('./config/email_details.ini')
```

as well as setting the working directory to C:/Python_Custom_Packages so that the root (./) is on the nearest common directory. Now I have done this as this is how the other jobs do it. I have been a developer for a few years mainly in java so have programming experience, and something about this setup doesn't sit right with me so ive done some googling to find the 'best practice' way of dealing with ini files (and other configs). Most examples state just use the following:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('email_details.ini')
```

Which to me means that the ini sits on the same directory path as the script.

My first question is, Is this best practice? (having the config and the script that utilises it in the same DIR) or is what the team do currently with a config folder in a different directory and pointing the workspace to the closest shared path as root and adding the dir ('./....Email_config.ini) a good idea. To me this will cause issues if migrating/moving the jobs etc.

The issue i am hitting other than the above query is that if i execute Test_Job_Email.py it uses its path as root meaning when i call Email.py inside this script it cant find the .ini

So my second question is. What is the best approach for ensuring the email_details.ini is picked up by the Email.py when its being executed from a total different script in a different path?

Note:

```
C:/Python_Custom_Packages/Classes/ 
C:/Python_Custom_Packages/Conf/
```

are in PYTHONPATH Environmental Variable already.

Sorry if any of this is confusingly written as I say I'm starting out with Python and rarely post on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find any definitive answers on best approach.

Answer (score 1):

So I still not 100% sure on the best practices but for ease it makes sense that the .ini be in the same path as the .py that calls it. that way you can add something like

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

before the read and that will get the path without the file of the current script i.e. the Email script regardless of where the script was executed. From there you can add it to the conf.read method as part of the path

```
conf.read(script_path + '/email_details.ini')
```

This could be a cheap workaround but its what i will be using for now.